# Syncronization on the producer-consumer problem

Tags: operating-system, buffer, ipc, semaphore

I have a homework problem about the producer-consumer relationship, which I can't understand where to start from.

Here is the problem:

> Please consider the **producer-consumer relationship** between processes
>   and suppose that a ***process P1*** sends a *5 byte message* through buffer to
>   ***process P2***. ***P2*** reads the string *"SSNNEMANE NCATA"* from the buffer,
>   while the message ***P1*** sent is *"CONNESSIONE MANCATA"*. What can you say
>   about their syncronization (realized with *semaphores*)?

Is anybody able to help? Thank you!

Comment: For sure?  Nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean sends a message through a 5 byte buffer.   You only posted a fragment, but I think the idea is to look at what should have happened; and compare it to what did, to generate hypothesis about how the buffer is being corrupted.

For example, how could we get the buffer into a state where it contains SSNE:

1. the sender should have been able to immediately fill the first 5 bytes with "CONNE" into indices [0..4] of the buffer.
2. After the receiver consumes 2 bytes from the buffer ("CO").
3. the sender can contribute "SS"; which would over-write the first two indices [0..1].
4. At this point the buffer would look like "SSNNE".

Hypothesis1:  The semaphore availability count is being used to represent free space in the buffer.   That count has been incorrectly initialized to 7 rather than 5, so the sender is corrupting the buffer.  In the steps above; step 3 is proceeding before step 2.

Hypothesis2:  The availability semaphore (Hypothesis1) is incorrectly used as a mutex and both processes are over-writing the head and tail buffer pointers independently.

Hypothesis3: ...

Now, test that hypothesis against the pattern you see for consistency - could it generate the entire result.

Finally, examine the code to see if this is indeed the case.

Effectively repeat this procedure of generating hypothesis until you find the solution.